# I got the following error while automate the webpage using testNG

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

```
package browserhandling;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class allwithxpath {
    public static WebDriver driver;
    @Test(priority=1)
    public void browserLaunch() throws InterruptedException{
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","f:\\chromedriver.exe");
        //Launch empty browser

        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

         driver.manage().window().maximize();

         //Open the bowser with respective Shopkio Url 
                driver.get("https://www.shopkio.com/");
                Thread.sleep(3000);

        //Click on Sarees link 
                WebElement ele=driver.findElement(By.id("clicked62"));
                JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
                js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='clicked62']")));

        //Click on on Item
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='bestselling']/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/a")).click();;

Thread.sleep(3000);

    }
    @Test(priority=2)
    public void addandcheckout() throws Exception{

        //Click on Add to Cart
                //driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/section[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[6]/div[2]/div/a[1]")).click();
                JavascriptExecutor js4=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
                js4.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='mhide']")));
        //Click on Checkout
                JavascriptExecutor js1=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
                js1.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='shopping-data']/div[3]/div[2]/a")));

    }

    @Test(priority=3)
    public void guestlogindetails() throws InterruptedException{
    //Click on Guest Login

                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='LoginDiv']/div[2]/a")).click();

        //Enter name in name field
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='first_name_guest']")).sendKeys("narasimha");

         //Enter phonenumber in ph.no field
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='mobile_no_guest']")).sendKeys("8688991234");

         //Enter Address in Address field
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='address_guest']")).sendKeys("hopefarm");

         //Enter zipcode in zipcode field
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='zip_code_guest']")).sendKeys("560066");

         //Select DropdownBox for State
                Select state=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='state_id_guest']")));
                state.selectByVisibleText("Karnataka");
                Thread.sleep(3000);

         //Select Dropdownbox for city

                Select cityname=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='city_id_guest']")));

                cityname.selectByVisibleText("Bengaluru");

         //Click on Submit Button      


                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='SaveAddress']")).click();
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

         //Click on Next Button

                JavascriptExecutor js2=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
                js2.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='SaveAddress1']")));

    }

    @Test(priority=4)
    public void placeorder(){
         //Click on Place Order

                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='cod']")).click();
        System.out.println("Order placed Successfuly");
        }
    }
```

Error as follows

> PASSED: browserLaunch FAILED: addandcheckout
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   browserhandling.allwithxpath.addandcheckout(allwithxpath.java:46)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:580)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:716)    at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:988)   at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)   at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
>
> FAILED: guestlogindetails java.lang.NullPointerException  at
>   browserhandling.allwithxpath.guestlogindetails(allwithxpath.java:57)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:580)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:716)    at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:988)   at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)   at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
>
> FAILED: placeorder java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   browserhandling.allwithxpath.placeorder(allwithxpath.java:99)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:580)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:716)    at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:988)   at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)   at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
>
> ===============================================
>       Default test
>
> ## Tests run: 4, Failures: 3, Skips: 0
>
> ## =============================================== Default suite Total tests run: 4, Failures: 3, Skips: 0

Comment: Hi there. What's your actual question? You've posted the error, but without a question to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I can see one issue in your code and likely it is the root-cause of your problem.

1. You have a static field `driver`
2. You're trying to initialize (probably that static) `driver` in your first test. However you're creating an object `WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();`that is only locally-visible in your first test. Thus your static `driver` field remains uninitialized
3. You refer to that static `driver` field in your other tests.

So here are few points I'd like to adivce

1. It is worth reading a book or pass a course on Java before starting to implement auto-tests. This time you get the exception because Java cares about you but the next time you will get no errors but just a false-positive/false negative result
2. Do not make your tests dependent on each other. Rather set up your driver in preconditions.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Alexey R. mentioned, do you also need a JavascriptExecutor? 
you can easily click on links, e.g.:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("clicked62")).click();
```

But mainly, since you are already using testNg, it would be better to initialize the browser `(driver = new ChromeDriver();)` in a `@Before` method (you can call this as:

```
public void initBrowser(){}
```

If you wish that way, the same driver will be initialized before each `@Test`.

And a sidenote: try to avoid using '*' in your xpath as the search scope in DOM is to wide. Its always preferrable to use a particular DOM element like `//input[] or //div[]`.